# $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/\langle (1,2)\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am told that the following proof shows that $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/\langle (1,2)\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

> The $1$ in the generator $(1, 2)$ of $\langle (1,2)\rangle$ shows that each coset of $\langle (1,2)\rangle$ contains a unique element of the form $(0, m)$, and of course, every such element of $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ is in some coset of $\langle (1,2)\rangle$. We can choose these representatives $(0, m)$ to compute in the factor group, which must therefore be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

But, I don't understand why every coset has unique $(0,m)$ form and what does that mean that "choose these representative~~~" and from this why is this isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: [Here is a tutorial on how to typeset math.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 2):

An idea, without needing *that* proof. Define

$$\phi:\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z\;,\;\;\phi(m,n):=2m-n$$

It's an easy exercise to show the above is a group homomorphism which is onto. What about its kernel?

$$x:=(m,n)\in\ker\phi\iff2m=n\iff x=(m,2m)=m(1,2)\in\langle\,(1,2)\,\rangle$$

And now just apply the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: Actually, I prefer this way. However, it seems little bit hard to define function so that it is homomorphism and kernel is subgroup generated. Is there any easy way to find this mapping?

Comment: @hho In some cases, as in this one, it is easy. In other ones it can be tough, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, each $(a, b)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ is congruent modulo $(1, 2)$ to $(0, b-2a)$. This should be immediate for you; if not, you should reread the section of your textbook on what the quotient process actually means.

Now suppose $(a, b)$ were also congruent modulo $(1, 2)$ to some $(0, c)$. Then $(0, b-2a)-(0, c)=(0, b-2a-c)=k(1, 2)$ for some $k$. But clearly $k=0$ is the only possibility, so $b-2a-c=0$, so $c=b-2a$.

So each $(a, b)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ is congruent modulo $(1, 2)$ to *exactly one* element of the form $(0, c)$; denote this $c$ by $h(a, b)$.

There are now three things to check:

- If $(a, b)$ is congruent modulo $(1, 2)$ to $(a', b')$, then $h(a, b)=h(a', b')$. *That is, $h$ is well-defined on $\mathbb{Z}^2/\langle (1, 2)\rangle$.*
- If $(a, b)=(u, v)+(x, y)$, then $h(a, b)=h(u, v)+h(x, y)$. *That is, $h$ respects the group operation.*
- $h(0, 0)=0$. *That is, $h$ sends the identity to the identity.*

Once we check these three properties, we'll have that $h$ gives a homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}^2/\langle (1, 2)\rangle$ to $\mathbb{Z}$. Since we have an explicit formula for $h$, $$h(a, b)=b-2a,$$ we know $h$ is surjective, and so this will complete the proof.

But checking these properties is very easy, again given that we have an explicit formula for $h$. For example, to see that $h$ sends the identity, we just compute $$0-2\times 0=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Recall that by the definition of the quotient group, two cosets $g_1 + H$ and $g_2 + H$ are equal in $G/H$ iff $g_1 - g_2 \in H$.  Also, recall that $\langle (1,2)\rangle = \{(m, 2m) : m \in \mathbb{Z}\}$, since this is the subgroup generated by all sums of $(1,2)$ and its inverse $(-1, -2)$.

Given a coset $(a,b) + \langle (1,2)\rangle \in \frac{\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}}{\langle (1,2) \rangle}$, we want to find another representative $(0,m)$ for the same coset.  Thus we need to find an element of $\langle (1,2) \rangle$ that, when added to $(a,b)$, cancels out the $a$ in the first entry.  What could we add to $(a,b)$ that is of the form $(m, 2m)$ to cancel out the $a$ in the first entry?  What should we pick $m$ to be?

Answer (score 0):

Elements of the abelian group $\Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{Z} / \langle (1,2) \rangle$ are cosets of the form
$$
\begin{align}
(a,b) + \langle (1,2) \rangle 
&= \{ (a,b) + n(1,2) \mid n \in \Bbb{Z} \} \\
&= \{ (a + n, b + 2n) \mid n \in \Bbb{Z} \}.
\end{align}
$$
A particular choice of $(a,b) \in \Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{Z}$ is called a *representative* of the coset.  Any two representatives $(a,b)$, $(a',b')$ of the same coset differ by an element of $\langle (1,2) \rangle$.  That is,
$$
(a',b') - (a,b) = n(1,2) \quad \text{for some } n \in \Bbb{Z},
$$
or in other words,
$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
a' - a &= n \\
b' - b &= 2n
\end{align}
\right.
$$

In order to construct a *well-defined* homomorphism out of this group, if you define the formula in terms of the representative $(a,b)$, then you need to make sure that it doesn't depend on that choice.  With a little bit of messing around, you might stumble upon 
$\varphi: \Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{Z} / \langle (1,2) \rangle \to \Bbb{Z}$, defined by

[Hover over the box to reveal the spoiler when you're ready.]

> $$ \varphi \bigl( (a,b) + \langle (1,2) \rangle \bigr) = 2a - b $$

You can check that $\varphi \bigl( (a,b) + \langle (1,2) \rangle \bigr) = \varphi \bigl( (a',b') + \langle (1,2) \rangle \bigr)$, so this map is well-defined.

---

Can you see why $\varphi$ is *one-to-one*?  How about *onto*?